# Mounting an electrical box to screws drilled into the ceiling

Tags: screws, junction-box

[image]A [plastic box junction box](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Carlon-1-Gang-12-cu-in-New-Work-Gray-Non-Metallic-Handy-Box-Case-of-36-B112HBR/202205583) shall be mounted to a drywall industrial ceiling with two screws.  The box will be filled with many low voltage wires before it is brought to the worksite (making it very difficult, if not impossible, to screw down from the inside).

Is there a clever method to first screw-in the screws to the ceiling, then mount the box to screws, which are protruding from the ceiling?

Comment: Who cares what the box is filled with? The pictured box only permits mounting screws on the two corner ears, so the screws will not impact anything preinstalled in the box interior.   You are obliged to install the box according to its labeling and instructions, NEC 110.3b.

Comment: Link corrected to reflect target box.

Answer (score 1):

You pull the wiring out of the box enough to allow you to attach the screws safely without nicking a wire.  *It really helps to hand-drive the screw with care, not just smash it in with a power-driver*.

If you don't like all that care, then you use a type of junction box that has ears on the outside, like this.

[image]

Or a metal box which, while you do not see any ears, they come in the accessory kit and you can attach them one of several ways.

[image]

Comment: I like the 'ears'.  This has inspired me: maybe I can also use a metal L-bracket to affix the exterior of the box to the ceiling.